# Laravel BelongsToThrough

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to filter `venue` by `country`

| Venue | City | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | id | id |
| name | name | name |
| city_id | country_id |  |

```
class Venue extends Model
{
    public function city() {
        return $this->belongsTo(City::class);
    }
}

class City extends Model
{
    public function country() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
    }
    public function venue() {
        return $this->hasMany(Venue::class);
    }
}

class Country extends Model
{
    public function city() {
        return $this->hasMany(City::class);
    }
}
```

I could filter the venue by `city` just only by doing this

```
    $venues = Venue::with('city')->whereHas('city', function($query) use($cityId){
        $query->where('id', $cityId);
    });
```

I need to filter the `venue` by `country` how to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple `whereHas` and chain relationship to access.

```
 $venues = Venue::with('city','city.country')->whereHas('city', function($query) use($cityId){
        $query->where('id', $cityId);
    })->whereHas('city.country', function($query) use($countryId){
        $query->where('id', $countryId);
    })->get();
```

Comment: relationship country  would be undefined on venue model